# Проблема со SlidingTab

Tags: android

http://www.fandroid.info/android-sliding-tabs-razdvizhnye-vkladki-v-stile-material-design/

Посмотрел урок по созданию вкладок в стиле Material design. Все работает, кроме нажатии на сами кнопки вкладок. Не знаю как решить эту проблему. 
В коде ничего не менял. Обработчики тоже не трогал.

Comment: Какая версия Android на вашем устройстве? Или вы использовали эмулятор?

Comment: Использую эмулятор, как и на уроке. Пробовал на разных версия

Comment: К сожалению причин может быть достаточно много, чтобы однозначно дать ответ. Советую вам попробовать сделать tabs по другому примеру (зачастую к примерам прикрепляется исходный код, можно будет сразу протестировать).

Comment: Я уже пробовал по двум урокам. У всех них работает, но я не могу понять, что у меня не так. Какие могут причины? Хотя бы парочку назовите)

Comment: Ну, попробуем поплясать с бубном:
При инициализации ViewPagerAdapter использовать getChildFragmentManager(). В целом большинство проблем заключается в проблемах с ViewPager.
К слову, никакие ошибки не выдаются?

Comment: Ошибок никаких нет. Работает Sliding, но вот нажатие на кнопки вкладок нет.

Comment: Странно, обычно или работает в комплексе или не работает вовсе.
А в логах когда нажимаете, прописывается Action того, что произошло нажатие?

Comment: Связано ли это как-то с toolbar? Я его вообще не ставлю, в уроках же он есть.

Comment: Конечно связано. ViewPager вешается на Toolbar.
Без tooblar по этим примерам работать не будет. Нужна другая трудоемкая реализация.
Я вам советую использовать TabLayout и на него вешать ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

Реализуйте вашу программу с применением TabLayout, и на него вешать ViewPager.

```
slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
```